# How to generate or create private / public key in flutter?

Tags: dart, rsa, private-key, public-key, key-generator

I need to generate a keypair in my Flutter app,  There is one library called RSA which does parse a pair of public/private keys and is able to encrypt and decrypt strings using them, but it doesn't have the ability to generate a new KeyPair (preferably from a given string).

How can I generate the keys in the first place? Am I missing something?

```
//Future to hold our KeyPair
Future<crypto.AsymmetricKeyPair> futureKeyPair;

//to store the KeyPair once we get data from our future
crypto.AsymmetricKeyPair keyPair;

Future<crypto.AsymmetricKeyPair<crypto.PublicKey, crypto.PrivateKey>> getKeyPair()
{
  var helper = RsaKeyHelper();
  return helper.computeRSAKeyPair(helper.getSecureRandom());
}
```

Comment: This has more to do with Dart than Flutter. Consider editing the tags and title

Comment: Hi have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy using the fast_rsa package:

```dart
import 'package:fast_rsa/fast_rsa.dart';
   
KeyPair keyPair1 = await RSA.generate(2048);
print(keyPair1.privateKey);
print(keyPair1.publicKey);
```

https://pub.dev/packages/fast_rsa